# Facebook Messenger API - How to Unsubscribe a user from a Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

Is there a way to programmatically unsubscribe a Facebook user so he doesn't receive any messages from the bot on my Facebook Page?

I can mark him in my database as unsubscribed so my program can check and not send him messages via Send APIs, but he will still receive broadcasts sent via Broadcasts API.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're able to unsubscribe the user by using your database and SendAPI, but can't do the same for the Broadcast API. In order for the user to not receive specific broadcasts, **you'll need to remove the broadcast label from the user's PSID** by using FB's Targeted Broadcast API.

For example, if you have a broadcast that is associated by a label *"MY_BROADCAST_LABEL_123"*, you'll need to:

1. associate all of your **subscribed** users' PSIDs to this broadcast label
2. remove that label associated to all of your **unsubscribed** users' PSIDs

Then, simply include the label *"MYBROADCAST_LABEL_123"* in the `custom_label_id` property of the request payload when you send the broadcast message, like this:

```
{    
    "message_creative_id": <YOUR_BROADCAST_MESSAGE_ID_HERE>,
    "custom_label_id": "MY_BROADCAST_LABEL_123"
}
```

To do all of the above, you should take a look at the FB documentation for [Targeting Broadcast Messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts) for all the implementation details you need. Do make sure that you're at least on Graph API v2.11.